# TextInputEditText addTextChangedListener Not Called When Typing

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I have a simple form with one `TextInputEditText` (Material Design component) and am unable to listen for text changes. Adding a `TextWatcher` with `addTextChangedListener` seems to have zero effect. When I run my app and type into the input with the virtual keyboard, none of the callbacks are called (debug breakpoints are not hit), and my `TextView` is not updated:

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var webBankingIdLayout: TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var webBankingIdInput: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webBankingIdLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.web_banking_id_input_layout)
        webBankingIdInput = TextInputEditText(webBankingIdLayout.context)
        textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_text)

        webBankingIdInput.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                s!!
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                s!!
                textView.text = s!!
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                s!!
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/web_banking_id_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/web_banking_id_text_input"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/web_banking_id_hint" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temp_text"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password_input_layout" />
```

If, however, I programatically set the text of the input field, then the callbacks are called and the `TextView` is updated.

```
webBankingIdInput.text = "Yippee!"
```

**Why doesn't my code work, and how can I listen to character entry into the text input?**

My goal is to keep a button hidden until the minimum number of characters are entered into the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need replace:

```
webBankingIdInput = TextInputEditText(webBankingIdLayout.context)
```

to:

```
webBankingIdInput = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.web_banking_id_text_input)
```

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I assumed that passing the context to the constructor would return the instance defined in the layout. Guess I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was caused by not having the android:inputType parameter set in the XML.